# Hide Bootstrap tabs until .active with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

You can check all my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/Magne/k6hqmtgo/

I'm currently working with Bootstrap and jQuery. What I want to do is to hide all the tabs but the first one and have them appear only after I have accessed one with my "Next" button. And then **stay visible**.

I'm trying to achieve this with my class `.ghost{display:none}` assigned to my `<li>` like this:

```
 <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Shipping</a></li>
 <li class="ghost"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Quantities</a></li>
 <li class="ghost"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a></li>
```

Then trying to make them visible with `.removeClass` or `.show` like this:

```
//This is supposed to make them visible
if ($('.ghost').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.ghost').show();
        }               
//Or this maybe?
if ($('.ghost').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.ghost').removeClass("ghost");
        }
```

Which doesn't work, I don't really know why.

You can check my code here:https://jsfiddle.net/Magne/18qz0pad/29/

I really appreciate the help

Thank you! :D

Comment: I am not sure that removing the class will make the property automaticly be set to true again. Try adding a class where you set the display to Display: initial, now remove the old class called .ghost

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried doing: 

`if ($('.ghost').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.ghost').addClass("shine");
        }`
And `.shine {display:initial}` but it's still not working. It's not even adding or removing the classes

Comment: Try haxxxton's answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css it more important than the js `show` function, instead if you use the `next` button to remove the `ghost` class you'll end up with the result you want

You already have a binding to the next button click, so we can leverage this code to remove the `ghost` class

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/k6hqmtgo/4/)**

**JS**

```
//Next and prev buttons
$('.btnNext').click(function(){
    var nextListItem = $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li');
    nextListItem.removeClass('ghost');
    nextListItem.find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

PS. you appear to not be using the `myTab a` js code, so i have removed it

Comment: Thank you! We are getting there, but this makes them all visible, I just want the one that is active... So for example: I go to Tab2 and it shows but Tab3 stays hidden until I go there. Can we somehow target only the next tab for the .removeClass ?

Comment: I did it! I removed the `#tab1`and targeted the `.next()` on your code like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Magne/k6hqmtgo/ Thank you a lot!

Comment: @MagneRaknaren, awesome, truly shows how many ways there are to skin a cat :) i would suggest the updated approach above however are it creates a few less event listeners, given you're already using the `btnNext` handler

Comment: @MagneRaknaren, please consider marking this solution as the answer to that searchers can find the help they are looking for in future